For AWS Lambda Functions created via .NET Core Minimal API, is it necessary to provision S3 Bucket storage?
AWS now allows you to convert a .NET 6+ Minimal API into a Lambda function by adding Lambda hosting to the services collection (i.e., builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.RestApi)).
From what I've read online, you are able to then deploy it to your AWS instance via CDK with just a few lines of TypeScript* code, e.g.:
export class MyLambdaStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const functionProps: lambda.FunctionProps = {
            functionName: 'my-lambda',
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_8,
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('../path/to/publish-folder'),
            handler: 'My.Lambda.Namespace',
            timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300)
        };

        new lambda.Function(this, "MyLambda", functionProps);
    }
} 

However, I've noticed that this example doesn't contain code for creating the S3 Bucket to save the code to.
Is is necessary for me to create the buckets?  Or does this new way of creating/deploying Lambdas obviate the need for me to do this?
*Yes, I realize CDK code can be written in C# or several other language, but my DevOps team prefers TypeScript.

The code is uploaded to the CDK Bootstrapping bucket. Check out the developer guide on Bootstrapping to familiarize yourself with the concepts: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html

As @gshpychka suggested you need to run cdk bootstrap first to bootstrap your AWS environment (AWS Account + Region).
Moreover, you can also compile your .NET app inside docker container using CDK Bundling feature. That way, you don't have to provide the path at lambda.Code.fromAsset('../path/to/publish-folder') manually. Refer https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/modernizing-with-aws/build-package-publish-dotnet-csharp-lambda-functions-aws-cdk/
